# How to call a URL without redirecting and get response

Tags: php, api, curl

I am getting response as *sent* when I am pasting  below URL in browser

```
http://www.example.com/smpp/sendsms?username=demo&password=demo&to=1234567890&from=demo&text=Your order demo123 have been completed
```

But when I use:-

```
file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/smpp/sendsms?username=demo&password=demo&to=1234567890&from=demo&text=Your order demo123 have been completed");
```

I gets following error

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/smpp/sendsms?username=demo&password=demo&to=1234567890&from=demo&text=Your
>   order demo123 have been completed) [function.file-get-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 4

I've tried using CURL but it is showing no output and sms not getting sent.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/smpp/sendsms?username=demo&password=demo&to=1234567890&from=demo&text=Your order demo123 have been completed");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've also un-commented `extension=php_curl.dll` in *php.ini* file and restarted server. but Nothing works.

Comment: Whats all this? `Your order demo123 have been completed` urls are like `Your+order+demo+123+have+been+completed`  I'd highly recommend using `urlencode `on that.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php See that blue text end ( in the block quote ), that should be a hint.

Comment: `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/smpp/sendsms?username=demo&password=demo&to=1234567890&from=demo&text=Your order demo123 have been completed");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);

?>`  it's returning bool(true). So what you want. Also take care what  `ArtisiticPhoenix`  suggested

Comment: Your forgetting `$result = curl_exec ($ch); curl_close ($ch);` to execute the curl request as well.  As @Anant said ( abbreviated here for readabillity )

Comment: @Anant - already updated my comment, didn't see it at first, hard to read that much code in a comment.  Cheers! ( ps I gave you an upvote :-p )  Nice catch.

Comment: @Anant - it's all good, great minds think alike, You should make it an aswer, as I believe it is the correct one.  I wouldn't use the file functions, because you need url stream wrappers.

Comment: `http://www.example.com/smpp/sendsms?username=demo&password=demo&to=1234567890&from=demo&text=Your order demo123 have been completed` by hitting it through browser it is not giving response as `sent `